# PYQT4 List item contents are disappearing when inserting it back into the list

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a pyqt4 setup with a custom widget as the item of the listwidget. I have two buttons in that custom widget to move it up or down the list by taking it and inserting it either 1 up or 1 down.

When it is inserted the item is still highlighted but the contents are gone.

Here is what is moving the item.

```
def ChangeInit(self, row, direction):
        item = self.initiativeList.takeItem(row)
        self.initiativeList.insertItem(row + direction, item)
```

row = the row the item is in
direction = 1 or -1 depending on which button is pressed

Any ideas why the item appears to be moved but the contents of it not being moved with it or at least not visible?

Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation of `QListWidget.addItem`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#addItem-1) states:

> **Warning:** A QListWidgetItem can only be added to a QListWidget once. Adding the same QListWidgetItem multiple times to a QListWidget will result in undefined behavior.

Although this can be interpreted in more than one way (i.e. adding one widget multiple times simultaneously, or adding it sequentially like you do) I sugest that you create a completely new `QListWidgetItem` object and insert *that* in the list, just to be sure. Otherwise I don't know if Qt will handle the underlying indices correctly.

P.S. next time I would add the general `PyQt` label unless it is a problem specific to PyQt4. This might get you some more views (you now only have two after 23 hours).

Comment: These should be their own objects. I have a different function that uses my InitCreatureObject class to make an object that it then inserts into the list. I can try just removing it and inserting a new one and see if that works then. Seems like a lot of extra processing just to move it up or down in the list.

Comment: Yes it seems to be more work than necessary. Another alternative would be to use a separate model and view. That is, use a `QListView` and implement your own model by inheriting from `QAbstractListModel`. This requires some effort, but if you want more than a simple list widget, it may well be worth it.

Comment: I tweaked my code to make a new item and just fill in what it needs based on the old item, it's not a pretty solution but it works. I'll look into the other recommendation you had if it still gives me trouble down the line. Thanks.